# view pager load more than one fragment data once

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

i am working tabs in App but when `fragment` loaded it load the data for two fragment . how to rectify that when i clock a `tab` it loaded only this tab data how to do this

this is my code for view pager
     // for tab selected event

```
private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager viewPager) {

    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    //int numberOfPages = 0;

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Matches_Tab(), "Matches");
    adapter.addFragment(new NewMatches_Tab(), "New matches");
    adapter.addFragment(new Similar_Matchs_Tab(), "Similar Matches");
    adapter.addFragment(new ShortlistTab(), "ShortListed");
    adapter.addFragment(new Viewed_My_Profile(), "View My Profile");
    adapter.addFragment(new ShortListedMeTab(), "ShortListed Me");
    adapter.addFragment(new Photo_Request_Received(), "Photo Request Received");
    //viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(numberOfPages);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    //onTabSelectedListener(viewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// view pager adapter
 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setUserVisibleHint`:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
            //You can do inside this method
        }
    }
}
```

this will return true if this fragment is in front of screen then do whatever you want inside of it.

Comment: how to use this method

Answer (score 0):

Load your data when fragment becomes visible by overriding setUserVisibleHint Method like below:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
       //Load your data here ...
    }
}
```

Secondly setOffScreenPageLimit(0) will not work as by default OFF SCREEN VALUE is 1 and value < 1 will not work.

Comment: how to use this method in fragment??